# Habilitar botão somente quando dois selects estiverem com valor diferente de 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia.

Estou com duvida para fazer uma validação em dois selects em jquery.

Eu preciso que o botão só habilite quando os dois selects estiverem com com algum valor selecionado.

Porém da forma que eu fiz, ele valida se o primeiro select não esta vazio, e o depois o segundo e se eu faço ao contrario, seleciono o segundo select primeiro, ele não entende.

Fiz a função completamente errada. Fiz a validação com o primeiro select e depois com o segundo, usando if. Algum pode me ajudar?

segue como está.

```
        $("#select-1").change(function(){
          if( $('#select-1').val() != 0 ){
            $("#select-2").change(function(){
              if( $('#select-2').val() != 0 ){
              botaoBuy.attr("disabled", false);
              botaoBuy.css("opacity","1");

              }else{
                botaoBuy.attr("disabled", true);
                botaoBuy.css("opacity","0.4");
              }
            });
          }else{
            botaoBuy.attr("disabled", true);
            botaoBuy.css("opacity","0.4");
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode chamar uma função que define o valor do atributo `disabled` quando houver mudança em um dos `<select>`:

```js
$(function(){
  
  var animals = $('#animals')
    , sports = $('#sports')
    , button = $('button')
  
  function handleButtonDisabledState(){
    button.attr('disabled', !animals.val() || !sports.val())
  }
  
  animals.on('change', handleButtonDisabledState)
  sports.on('change', handleButtonDisabledState)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='animals'>
  <option selected disabled>Animais</option>
  <option value='dog'>Cachorro</option>
  <option value='cat'>Gato</option>
</select>

<select id='sports'>
  <option selected disabled>Esportes</option>
  <option value='basketball'>Basquete</option>
  <option value='soccer'>Futebol</option>
</select>

<button disabled>Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Resposta concisa e correta, sem contar que faz cache dos elementos DOM para não desperdiçar recurso computacional. +1

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar dessa forma abaixo, quando houver uma mudança em um dos dois, ele checa se o valor de ambos os campos foi alterado ou não:

```
$("#select-1, #select-2").change(function(){
    if( $('#select-1').val() != 0 && $('#select-2').val() != 0 )
    {
        botaoBuy.attr("disabled", false);
        botaoBuy.css("opacity","1");
    } else {
        botaoBuy.attr("disabled", true);
        botaoBuy.css("opacity","0.4");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dá para fazer assim:

```js
function eventoChange() {

  $("#comprar").prop('disabled',
     ($('#select-1').val() == 0 || $('#select-2').val() == 0)
  );

}

$("#select-1, #select-2").change(eventoChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-1" selected="0">
  <option value="0">--selecione o produto--</option>
  <option value="1">Paçoquita</option>
  <option value="2">Pé de moleque</option>
</select>

<select id="select-2" value="0">
  <option value="0">--forma de pagamento--</option>
  <option value="1">Dinheiro</option>
  <option value="2">Cartão</option>
</select><br><br>

<button id="comprar" disabled>Comprar</button>
```